# How to show only multirow results in pivoted pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Complete newbie, first time posting. My data frame:

[image: This is my dataframe]

I am running this code over it

```
pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(shop_df, index=['Fruits', 'Location', 'Readiness'], values='Price')
```

and it correctly gives the pivoted result:

[image: result]

However, I would like only multi-line results to show like following

[image: only multi-line result]

How do I achieve that exactly?

Comment: Create small samples of your dataframe and put it here in a way that can be copied in a text editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input data is taken from @DNay in the answer.
Reset pivot_df.

```
pivot_df = pivot_df.reset_index()
```

Count number of fruits as in groupby.

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame(pivot_df.groupby('Fruits')['Location'].count()).reset_index()

ndf.columns=['Fruits', 'Count']
```

Select only fruits that have more than one rows.

```
pivot_df[pivot_df['Fruits'].isin(list(ndf.loc[ndf['Count'] > 1, 'Fruits']))]
```

Comment: Thank you, Ruthger.
I don't understnad line ndf.columns=['Fruits', 'Location']
and it gives ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 2 elements

Comment: @DNay: I just changed it, should work now. Could you run it again?

Comment: Perfect! This gets rid of all single line occurences in the dataframe, and gets me closer to what I want! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dani, let me try.
This is a datafreame:

```
import pandas as pd
shop_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Order_ID' : [232, 344, 452],
    'Fruits' : ['Apples', 'Apples', 'Pairs'],
    'Cultivar' : ['Cripps Pink', 'Braeburn', 'Bosc'],
    'Readiness' : ['Green', 'Irrelevant', 'Matured'],
    'Price' : [11, 12, 8],
    'Location' : ['Lost', 'Sold Out', 'Warehouse'],
    'Source' : ['Bobs Farm', 'Bettys', 'Bettys']})
shop_df.set_index(['Order_ID'], inplace=True)
shop_df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

This is pivot command over my dataframe:

```
pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(shop_df, index=['Fruits', 'Location', 'Readiness'], values='Price')
```

but it gives result with 3 rows [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzWd3.jpg), but I only want to see two first, for Apples only (without Pairs).[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp24U.jpg)

How do I do that?